# Clipboard in Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, clipboard

I have CSV Content in Angular 1 that I want to copy to clipboard. I am using clipboard.js https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js
If I am giving clipboard text with button, it is getting copied.

```
<button class="btn" data-clipboard-text="Gets copied">
Copy to clipboard</button>
```

But if I am dynamically setting the text like below, nothing gets copied.

```
new Clipboard('.btn', {
    text: $scope.test;
});
```

$scope.test has the CSV Content

Anything that i am missing ?

Comment: The documentation says that it expects `text` to be a string. Is that actually what the CSV content is at that point? Can you update your question to include the rest of the code around that clipboard call?

Comment: It worked, i created tab separated csv and  used new Clipboard('.copy',{text : function(){   
   return $scope.test; }});